# Is there any way of getting an output of all the header links because iv got none and no error as well

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Tried using beautiful soup for Scraping header links out of Bing but I don't get any errors nor output.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

search = input("Search for:")
params = {"q": search}
r = requests.get("http://www.bing.com/search", params=params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
results = soup.find("ol", {"id": "b_results"})
links = soup.findAll("li", {"class": "b_algo"})

for item in links:
    item_text = item.find("a").text
    item_href = item.find("a").attrs["href"]

    if item_text and item_href:
        print(item_text)
        print(item_href)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify `User-Agent` HTTP header to obtain the results:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.bing.com/search'
params = {'q': 'tree'}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params).content, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('.b_algo a'):
    print(a.text, a['href'])
```

Prints:

```
tree｜好きな物語と出逢えるサイト https://tree-novel.com/
sustainably stylish home furniture Hong Kong | TREE https://tree.com.hk/
Chairs & Benches https://tree.com.hk/furniture/chairs-benches
Desks https://tree.com.hk/furniture/desks
Living Room https://tree.com.hk/rooms/living-room
Bedroom https://tree.com.hk/rooms/bedroom
Finishing Touches https://tree.com.hk/furniture/finishing-touches
Entryway https://tree.com.hk/rooms/entryway
Tree | Definition of Tree by Merriam-Webster https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tree
Tree | Definition of Tree at Dictionary.com https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tree
tree | Structure, Uses, Importance, & Facts | Britannica https://www.britannica.com/plant/tree
Tree Images · Nature Photography · Free Photos from Pexels ... https://www.pexels.com/search/tree/
```

Comment: Do you know what the problem with my code was? Because my friend had the same one and his was working absolutely fine whereas mine just wasn't yielding any output..

Comment: @SanskarB.C. The problem is you have to specify `User-Agent` HTTP header in `requests.get()`

Comment: ooo headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}.. you mean this... so this is like a universal header for requests.get or is it always differet.. I had never seen a header like this so.. Im kinda confused

Comment: @SanskarB.C. It's how the HTTP protocol works. The browser will send request to the server (with some headers, among them is `User-Agent` header that identifies the browser). By default, `requests` sends different header to server and the server responds differently than to classic browser.

Comment: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0.. Could I have used this User-Agent as header as well?

Comment: Hey I had the same problem while downloading images from bing into a directory and this time I used the user agent as well.. I'll post that too. can you see what the problem in that is.. I used BYtesIO and stuff but again the same problem .... your idea helped me in the previous one but can you look at this one.. ill be posting it.. But thankyou for the help before

Comment: @SanskarB.C. To not clutter the comments, post it as a new question here on StackOverflow. I'll gladly look at it.

Comment: I just did.. Thank you again!

Comment: what would be the Http header for https://www.ultimate-guitar.com/explore this website.. Im tryinna scrap things from this site as well..